# Boolean Attributes with jQuery is inconsistent accross Browsers

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, boolean, attr

I create an attribute called "hasAgreed" to check whether I should treate or dismiss the values of a form.  I used this instead of relying on the click of the OK button since I want to be able to close the form sometimes when the user press Enter in the text input.

The problem I have is that if I do `$('#formElement').attr('hasAgreed')`, I get different values.

Firefox returns a string "true"  `( $('#formElement').attr('hasAgreed') == 'true')`
IExplorer returns a boolean `true`, `($('#formElement').attr('hasAgreed') == true)`
Chrome seems to be fine with both versions.

Is there a way to set a bool value using the `attr()` function of jQuery so that is consistent accross multiple browsers?

Comment: That's because you should use `.prop` instead.